# spring openapi autocodegen is generating delegates but APIs not getting exposed

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, openapi

I am trying to use spring openapi codegen to generate the APIs.
My expectations is spring openapi generator should generate some default models and a basic unimplemented controller delegate. So that I can implement it into my own controller layer and use it for exposing business logic as per my own requirement.

Now issue with me is, I am partially able to integrate the spring openapi codegen because I could see models and interfaces are generated successfully without failures.

But the problem is when I am implementing the autogenrated delegated into my controller class, my APIs aren't getting exposed due to which they are showing me an `404` error.

Also neither I am able to access the swagger UI at `http://localhost:8956/swagger-ui/index.html`

Please assist me what I am doing wrong here

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jainva.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        For rendering the spring UI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/jackson-databind-nullable -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>6.0.0</version>
                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.openapi.gen.springboot.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.openapi.gen.springboot.dto</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My controller file :

```
package com.jainva.api.controllers;

import com.jainva.api.http.models.CreateEmployeeRequestBody;
import com.jainva.api.services.EmployeServices;
import com.openapi.gen.springboot.api.EmployeesDataApiDelegate;
import com.openapi.gen.springboot.dto.EmployeesData;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.*;


@RestController
@Service
public class EmployeesController implements EmployeesDataApiDelegate {

    private final EmployeServices empServices;

    public EmployeesController(EmployeServices empServices) {
        this.empServices = empServices;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/v1/employee")
    public void createEmployee(@RequestBody CreateEmployeeRequestBody body) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Post request to the server from controller layer");
            empServices.createEmployee(body);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
                    .body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeesData> getAllEmployeesData() {
        System.out.println("Controller layer for get all employees");
        try {
            EmployeesData ed = new EmployeesData();
            ed.setEmployees(empServices.getAllEmployees());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(ed);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);

        }
    }

    @GetMapping("api/v1/response")
    public String response() {
        return "Successful working server";

    }


}
```

Comment: can you show us your openapi config ?
you have to override functions from the generated interfaces in the Controller

Comment: @P.Dieterich What do you mean when you say openapi config. I haven't done anything specific in terms of configuration, whatever configuration I done is present in `pom.xml`

Comment: if i undersand you correct you want to generate java code from a OpenAPI specification, right?

Comment: Your code is being generated to a package called `com.openapi.gen.springboot`, but your code lives in `com.jainva.api`.  Is this a multi-module build?  Is the `pom.xml` you provided only for the `com.openapi.gen.springboot` package?  Can you share your configuration for the `com.jainva.api` module?  Your `pom.xml` and Spring configuration are most important here for the debugging.  However, I'm going to assume that your configuration isn't properly adding the configuration from the generated classes.

Comment: Have you found a solution of your problem? I faced the exact same issue now :/ 
BTW ... you don't need both annotations @RestController @Service, the service one is sufficient since they both are @Component and the delegate is used by a generated @Controller class (``@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.dataHubRegulatoryData.base-path:}")``)

Comment: Ok ... in my case it was packages scanning problem - my main class was placed in a wrong package and the scanner was not detecting the components provided by the the other maven module.

Answer (score 0):

did you activate the springdoc in your application.yml(application.properties)  ?

i use in my application.yml

```
 springdoc:
        api-docs:
            enabled: true
        swagger-ui:
          enabled: true
          path: /swagger-ui
```

Comment: Thanks @P. Dieterich , No I didn't had it integrated before but after your recommendation I tried that too but still I am unable to access the UI.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with springdoc and doesn't address the issue of his API interfaces not being properly exposed.  The generator has a property called `useSwaggerUI` which is enabled by default.  The post shows this isn't modified, so the url is enabled.  The issue here with Spring configuration, not springdoc.

Comment: @tbatch you right,  I read it as two questions..